# Cover black gas pipe in basement ceiling

Tags: code-compliance, gas

I am remodeling my basement and have a concern about the black steel gas pipe that runs along the ceiling (below the joists). I plan to strap the ceiling, so I could potentially cover the pipe up with drywall, but is this legal? The only thing I can find in the code book is potentially allowing access to the weird "T" intersection in the photos below. We also might just drywall directly up to the pipe but not cover it and leave it exposed and painted white (for a slightly mechanical look).

This is in Maryland (Montgomery County). Any thoughts?

[image: gas pipe]

*(ps: ignore the badly installed window; this was discovered when we tore down the existing walls)*

Comment: That's a drip leg, which probably requires ready access by code. You'd probably need to specify a location/code for definitive answers.

Comment: yeah i figured that required access. This is in Maryland (Montgomery County), if that makes any difference.

Comment: The "weird T"  is how it is supposed to be done. It is a dripleg that can catch any solid contaminants that might be in the gas.

Comment: I normally install drip legs at the appliance after the shutoff so they can be cleaned without shutting down the entire home. This could have been for an additional planned appliance.

Answer (score 1):

Also in Montgomery County, MD, though that probably doesn't matter much. My similar pipe had a leak once at a joint between two sections, and if it had been covered with drywall that would have been a bit of a repair job (which I have had to do for water leaks).

A drop ceiling or other easily removable (i.e., no tools needed) covering may be a good solution. You could also have a hinged "door" made out of plywood, painted to match the drywall of the rest of the ceiling.

Comment: Thanks. Ideally we are trying to not drop the ceiling at all. Part of the basement is already 7' 1" tall (without finishes). So dropping the ceiling at all starts to cause a problem for headroom and I believe code technically requires 7' height with finishes for a livable space. This pipe used to have a very tiny bulk head around it and we hated it. So just researching other options.